# LWJGL methods missing

Tags: java, c++, opengl, lwjgl

Since I can't find any lwjgl books ( I doubt they exist) I'm learning opengl from a C++ book , and it was going nice until I found a little problem.

Some methods that are used by this book (quite a new book) are missing so I checked the github  for lwjgl and I found this :

[image: What I found on github]

I'm not a native english speaker but from what I understand its still a work in progress?

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text! Copy-paste the text into your question instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes lwjgl is still under construction.
OpenGL is basicly same in both c++ and lwjgl, so I would stick to language you are comfortable with. I'm still learning lwjgl myself, but I think it doesn't lack anything that would be essental for game development.